# Import "celery" could not be resolved

Tags: celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I know this has something to do with python not recognizing the standard library celery but I haven't found anything helpful online so far:

pip freeze output:

```
amqp==5.0.9
asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.3
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.11
click==8.0.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
Deprecated==1.2.13
Django==3.2.12
django-celery-beat==2.2.1
django-celery-results==2.2.0
django-environ==0.8.1
django-timezone-field==4.2.3
djangorestframework==3.13.1
greenlet==1.1.2
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.10.1
importlib-resources==5.4.0
kombu==5.2.3
Mako==1.1.6
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
numpy==1.22.2
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.27
psycopg2==2.9.3
pyparsing==3.0.7
python-crontab==2.6.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.19.2
pytz==2021.3
redis==4.1.4
requests==2.27.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.31
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.8
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
wrapt==1.13.3
zipp==3.7.0
```

When trying to import celery to my tasks.py it shows this warning/error indicating that it can't import the library:

[image]

This is my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apis.apps.ApisConfig',
    'users',
    'django_celery_beat',
    'rest_framework',
    'environ'
]

#Celery, Celery Beat and Redis settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER", "redis://redis:6379")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_BACKEND", "redis://redis:6379")
if CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND == 'django-db':
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_celery_results',]
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'United States/Mountain'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

this is my celery.py file in my project directory:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
 
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cds_web.settings')
app = Celery('cds_web')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
 
app.conf.timezone = 'Mountain'
 
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "every_thirty_seconds": {
        "task": "users.tasks.thirty_second_func",
        "schedule": timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
}
 
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

and here is my project directory's init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

I can't see where I've gone wrong. Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the output for `pip freeze`? are you sure you installed `celery`?

Comment: Just check whether celery working or not.This import error usually shows in mine also but when I run celery it works fine.The main problem for showing this is your celery setting file (celery.py)will be in your project setting folder and your task will be in your app folder.Just try import like 'from projectname.celery import shared_task'

Comment: @ItayB Here is my pip freeze output: (see initial post)